# Cannot open a file in visual studio 2022

Tags: c, visual-studio-2022

In my programming class I need to use information that is stored in U07.inc file, but the program gives me error E1696 cannot open source file "U07.inc" even though its in the same folder as the program source file (C:\Users\Votrsa\source\repos\Task7\Task7).

Any idea what could be wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

typedef enum { kus = 1, kg } Jednotka;
typedef union { int kus; float kg; } Mnozstvi;
typedef struct { const char* potravina; Jednotka jednotka; Mnozstvi mnozstvi; } Pohyb;

#include "U07.inc"

int main() {
    const Pohyb pohyby[] = POHYB;
    int pocetPohybu = sizeof(pohyby) / sizeof(Pohyb);
    while (1) {
        printf("Zadejte potravinu:\n");
        char potravina[20];
        scanf("%s", potravina);
        if (!isalpha(potravina[0])) {
            break;
        }
        int nalezena = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pocetPohybu; i++) {
            if (strcmp(pohyby[i].potravina, potravina) == 0) {
                if (pohyby[i].jednotka == kus) {
                    printf("%s %Of %s\n", potravina, pohyby[i].mnozstvi.kus, "kusu");
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s %.2f %s\n", potravina, pohyby[i].mnozstvi.kg, "kg");
                }
                nalezena = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!nalezena) {
            printf("potravina nenalezena\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried putting the U07.inc file in different folders in the project

Comment: Same "folder" inside the Visual Studio project? Or same *directory* on disk? They are different things.

Comment: When using "U07.inc" as an include file, have you added it to the list of include files in the project?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is stored at C:\Users\Votrsa\source\repos\Task7\Task7

Comment: Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build-log (as text) into the question itself. It *is* a build error, and not an IntelliSense error? They are (also) two different things.

Comment: I recommend this. Open the X64 native tools command prompt for VS 2022. Type `cd C:\Users\Votrsa\source\repos\Task7\Task7`. Type `cl yourprogram.cpp`. Do you see this error? Type `type U07.inc`. Does this show the content of the file? Type `dir`. Is `U07.inc` there?